# Why is findFragmentByTag() returning null

Tags: java, android-fragments, android-fragmentactivity, fragmentmanager

In MainActivity.java:

```
FragmentManager fr = getSupportFragmentManager();
if (fr.getBackStackEntryCount()>0 && 
    fr.getBackStackEntryAt(fr.getBackStackEntryCount()-1).getName().equals("CommunityLoggedIn")){
          Community backstackEntry= (Community) fr.findFragmentByTag("CommunityLoggedIn");
          if (backstackEntry!=null)
             Log.i("finFragmentByTag", "is not null");
            //fr.beginTransaction().remove(backstackEntry).commit();->NPE Exception because backstackEntry is 0
Log.i("BackstackCount", String.valueOf(getSupportFragmentManager().getBackStackEntryCount()));
Log.i("NameLastItem", getSupportFragmentManager().getBackStackEntryAt(getSupportFragmentManager().getBackStackEntryCount()-1).getName());
```

output is:

```
I/BackStackCount: 1
I/NameLastItem: CommunityLoggedIn
```

In Community.java:

```
FragmentManager fr=Community.super.getActivity().getSupportFragmentManager();
fr.beginTransaction().addToBackStack("CommunityLoggedIn").commit();
```

So Why am I getting NPE ?? We can see that the entry is in the backstack with help of `Log.i` and `if condition`, So if its in the bakcstack it must exist and if it exist why is then `findFragmentByTag()` returning `null`???

Am I understading the docu wrong:

> Finds a fragment that was identified by the given tag either when
> inflated from XML or as supplied when added in a transaction. This
> first searches through fragments that are currently added to the
> manager's activity; if no such fragment is found, then all fragments
> currently on the back stack are searched.

If no such Fragment is found then Fragments on the backstack are searched?

Is there any way to remove the transaction from the backstack without popping it?

I think even if this would work only the fragment would be removed without removing the whole transaction.

Comment: The [addToBackStack() documentation](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/FragmentTransaction#addToBackStack(java.lang.String)) doesn't say anything about setting a `tag` for the `Fragment`. Is a `tag` added somewhere in your code?

Comment: no only the tag for the transaction is added

Comment: If the Fragment has no tag, you can't find with a tag.

Comment: Thanks I thought that "communityLoggedIn" was the Fragments Tag